# How to cut multiple strings from txt filec#

Tags: c#, string, file, split, cycle

I tried a lot of possible solutions to this problem but it never seems to work. My problem is the following: I have a txt file with several lines. Each line has something like:

```
xxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxx yyyyyy
...
```

I want to store in one array of strings the `xxxxx` and in another array the `yyyyy`, for each line on the txt file, something like

```
string[] x;
string[] y;

string[1] x = xxxxx; // the x from the first line of the txt
string[2] x = xxxxx; // the x from the second line of the txt
string[3] x = xxxxx; // the x from the third line of the txt
```

...

and the same for `string[] y`;

... but i have no idea how to...

I would very much appreciate if someone showed me how to make the cycle for this problem i have.

Comment: the question didnt format the text that good... in the file.txt, each line has xxxxx yyyyy.

Comment: So do you have two (only two) categories of strings which you'd like to split to two different arrays? Or do you need to check for number of categories(duplicates)?

Comment: only 2 categories, xxxxx and yyyyy

Comment: is this not more like, store odd tokens in array one, and even tokens in array two?

Comment: Will x and y strings always be separated by one space? Will each line always start with x, or does it follow from the previous line?

Comment: idk wat you mean, I know that they are divided by a space (' ')... i wanna split the line of the txt file (split the xxxx from the yyyyy), and store the xxxx in on array of strings and the yyyy in annother rray of string... and do that for every line

Comment: So, you need to get the "odd" strings in one array and the "even" ones in another?

Comment: xxxxx and yyyyy is just an example... the value is diferent... all i know is that its only 2 things and they are separated by a space

Comment: You have already used a right word as a tag: *split*. Need more hints?

Comment: If one line ends with xxxxx, does the next start with yyyyy? Or do they all start with xxxxx? I understand x and y are examples, but I'mw anting to know if each line starts with the first category, or if it follows from the previous line

Comment: for example... in one line on the txt file i have "12345 abc", i need to stored the 12345 in string1[0] and the abc in string2[0], and so on for each line on the file

Comment: yes, each lin starts with the thing i wanna store in the x array

Comment: so it will always be first part of line goes to the x array and second part goes to the y array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq for this:

```
string test = "xxxxx yyyyyy xxxxx yyyyyy xxxxx yyyyyy xxxxx yyyyyy";
string[] testarray = test.Split(' ');
string[] arrayx= testarray.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray<string>();
string[] arrayy = testarray.Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray<string>();
```

Basically,this code splits the string by a space, and then puts the even strings in one array and the odd ones in another.

**Edit**

You say in the comments you don't understand this: `Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).`  What it does is taking the position of each string (i) and does a mod of it with 2. This means, it divides the position by 2 and checks if the remain equals 0. It is the way to get if a number is odd or even.

**Edit2**

My first answer only works for one line. For several ones(as your input source is a file with several lines), you'll need to do a `foreach` loop. Or you can do something like the next sample code: read all the lines, join them in a single string, and then run the prevously showed code on the result:

```
string[] file=File.ReadAllLines(@"yourfile.txt");
string allLines = string.Join(" ", file); //this joins all the lines into one
//Alternate way of joining the lines
//string allLines=file.Aggregate((i, j) => i + " " + j); 
string[] testarray = allLines.Split(' ');
string[] arrayx= testarray.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray<string>();
string[] arrayy = testarray.Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: this works even if the xxxxx and yyyyy is another thing? im asking because my brain kinda froze trying to understand the .Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0) part :p

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter what the values are, as long as they're separated by a single space

Comment: This solution does not relay on the content,only in the position

Comment: Another way to join all lines is: `string allLines = string.Join(" ", file);`

Comment: You are right @vyrp. That`s a simpler way also, i would update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, xxxxx and yyyyyy show up repeatly, which in case something like that 11111 222222 11111 222222 11111 222222
There is an ' ' space between them, so

```
1. you may split the line one by one within a loop
2. use ' ' as delimiter when split the line
3. use a counter to differentiate whether the string is odd or even and store them separately within another loop
```

Comment: Be careful that the delimiter is a char, and should be marked as ' '

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have multiple lines, each line with two strings. Then, here is an answer that uses a plain old for:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is just an example. In your case you would read the text from a file
        const string text = @"x y
xx yy
xxx yyy";
        var lines = text.Split(new[]{'\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var xs = new string[lines.Length];
        var ys = new string[lines.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) 
        {
            var parts = lines[i].Split(' ');
            xs[i] = parts[0];
            ys[i] = parts[1];
        } 
    }
```